# 自作Sphinx拡張のコードの一部にSphinxのコードを流用している場合の、Copyrightの書き方について

Tags: ライセンス, sphinx

BSDライセンスのため、流用そのものについては問題ないと判断しています。

どちらかといえばリスペクト的な意味でSphinxの名前を出しておきたい、という趣旨です。
一般的な表記方法などあれば教えてもらえると助かります。

#### 質問

例えば、`sphinx/builders/html/__init__.py` には次のような記載があります。

```
sphinx.builders.html
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Several HTML builders.

:copyright: Copyright 2007-2021 by the Sphinx team, see AUTHORS.
:license: BSD, see LICENSE for details.
```

このコードの一部を流用しているソースファイルについて、次のように記載すればいいでしょうか。

```
Forbar extention
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
A Sphinx Indexer.

:copyright: Copyright 2021 by @koKekkoh.
:license: BSD, see LICENSE for details.

This part of the code uses sphinx/builder/html.

:copyright: Copyright 2007-2021 by the Sphinx team, see AUTHORS of Sphinx.
:license: BSD, see LICENSE of Sphinx for details.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

元が2条項BSDライセンスなので、以下が条件となります。

- 元のライセンスホルダーの名前を出す必要はありません
- 許可無く貢献者の名前を宣伝に用いてはいけないという条項もありません（3条項だとある）

ということで、2条項BSDライセンスに則っていれば後は自由です。

```
This part of the code uses sphinx/builder/html.
```

上記の部分は、私であればリポジトリのURLを書いて、 `based on <URL>` 等と書くと思います。

ただ、以下を含めるのはちょっと違う気がします。

```
:copyright: Copyright 2007-2021 by the Sphinx team, see AUTHORS of Sphinx.
:license: BSD, see LICENSE of Sphinx for details.
```

この複製したコードのライセンスホルダーはSphinxチームにはなく、複製者にあると思うためです。